# How to set the 'Before' and 'After' ordering for tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle, and I wanted to execute two tasks right before and right after the `test` task from the `java` plugin. Let's call them `doBeforeTest` and `doAfterTest`. So that I had the following execution ordering when running `gradle build` command:

```
...
doBeforeTest
test
doAfterTest
...
```

I wrote the following code:

```
task doBeforeTest {
    doFirst() {
        println 'Do before test'
    }
}
task doAfterTest {
    doFirst() {
        println 'Do after test'
    }
}
test.dependsOn doBeforeTest
test.mustRunAfter doBeforeTest
doAfterTest.dependsOn test
doAfterTest.mustRunAfter test
```

But I get the foolowing result:

```
doBeforeTest
...
testClasses
test
check
...
```

Where `doAfterTest` hasn't called at all.

I was able to call the tasks in the expected order just when I added the following:

```
doBeforeTest.mustRunAfter testClasses
check.dependsOn doAfterTests
```

I just can't figure out why the `doAfterTest` is not called when I set it to be dependent on `test` task.

Is there any better solution? I read several answers related to task ordering but still couldn't find the proper way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'execution order'? You ran *e.g.* gradlew by calling:

```
doBeforeTest
test
doAfterTest
```

Executions via `gradlew`?

In any case:

First of all, think about whether or not this call of yours makes sense:

```
test.dependsOn doBeforeTest
test.mustRunAfter doBeforeTest
```

Because a dependency on something already implies, that `test` must run after `doBeforeTest`.

`doAfterTest` is not called in your first test, because you *do not call it*. I think you have an error in understanding how `dependsOn` works. It is a one-way street! This means this code:

```
doAfterTest.dependsOn test
doAfterTest.mustRunAfter test
```

...does **NOT** mean that if `test` is executed, then `doAfterTest` is executed *after*. It **ONLY** means if `doAfterTest` is executed, then `test` will be executed prior. Again, `doAfterTest.dependsOn test` is a sufficient statement, `doAferTest.mustRunAfter test` does not do anything in this case.

As mentioned, dependency is a one-way street. If you want X to happen *before* Y, then Y depends on X. This is in your example `doBeforeTest`. If you want X to happen *after* Y, then X depends on Y. This means, you would need to call the task that is last in chain and it then calls all of its dependencies.

You can model it like this:

Assume you have a task `myPipeline`. You want to execute tasks `doBeforeTest`, `test` and `doAfterTest` in that very order. You can now set up the task like this:

```
% Note: The order of declarations does not matter!
myPipeline.dependsOn test
myPipeline.dependsOn doAfterTest
myPipeline.dependsOn doBeforeTest

test.mustRunAfter doBeforeTest
doAfterTest.mustRunAfter test
```

And you're done. Now you call `gradlew myPipeline` and none of the other tasks, and the order of execution will be what you are looking for. If you want to omit `myPipeline` you can also set up `doAfterTest` like this:

```
doAfterTest.dependsOn test
doAfterTest.dependsOn doBeforeTest

test.mustRunAfter doBeforeTest
```

Then you can call `gradlew doAfterTest` and again your entire pipeline executes as expected.

This should be enough to get you started. Just remember, dependencies are one-way. A task *A* can depend on tasks *B, C, D*, which means they will run before *A* and you can also assign in which order *B, C, D* must be executed if you like. But if you need something to run **after** A, then you need to call that something, like *F* and let it depend on *A*. In the logic of Gradle tasks declare what they need before they are executed. They do not declare what is done afterwards.

Comment: What a great and comprehensive answer! Thanks a lot!